# 4 player pong game's collision isn't working

Tags: java, graphics, collision

I'm at the end of my first computor science course of highschool and we aren't forced to create a four play pong game. I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get my collision on the paddles work, right now I can controll them using W and S for the blue paddle, U and J for the red one, the left and right arrow keys for the green, and my mouse for the yellow paddle. For some reason there is random colliosion in the top left and both bottom right and left corners of my frame. None of my classmates know what's wrong with my code, and my teacher makes me feel like an idiot when I ask for help. PLEASE dm me or comment if you have a solution or wanna see my code and we could see what's wrong with it.

Thank you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Pong extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener, MouseMotionListener {

    // Declare global variables
    private Ball ball;
    private Paddle paddle1, paddle2, paddle3, paddle4;
    private int xDir, yDir;
    private Timer t;
    private int p1Score, p2Score, p3Score, p4Score;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Pong();
    }

    public Pong() {
        // Declare and initialize Ball and paddle object
        ball = new Ball(425, 300, 20, 20, Color.WHITE);
        paddle1 = new Paddle(20, 350, 30, 150, Color.BLUE);
        paddle2 = new Paddle(425, 20, 150, 30, Color.YELLOW); 
        paddle3 = new Paddle(790, 350, 30, 150, Color.RED);     
        paddle4 = new Paddle(425, 770, 150, 30, Color.GREEN);

        //Declare and initialize an ImageIcon object:
        ImageIcon ball = new ImageIcon("ball.png");

        // Initialize the two variables that will determine how many pixels the ball will move horizontally and vertically
        xDir = 10;
        yDir = 10;

        // Initialize Timer object and set interval to 50 milliseconds
        t = new Timer(50, this);

        // Add the key listener and set focus to the panel
        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setFocusable (true);

        // Set properties of JPanel object
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        // Declare, initialize and set properties of JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(this);
        frame.setSize(850, 850);
        frame.setTitle("4 Player Pong");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Start the timer
        t.start();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // If Player 1 presses the Up or Down arrows, the paddle will move 20 pixels Vertically
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            paddle1.moveVertically(-20);
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            paddle1.moveVertically(20);
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            paddle4.moveHorizontally(-20);
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            paddle4.moveHorizontally(20);
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_U) {
            paddle3.moveVertically(-20);
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_J) {
            paddle3.moveVertically(20);
        }
    }


    //Unimplemented methods
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}


    //If Player 2 moves his mouse right or left, the paddle will move the same distance
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        paddle2.setX(e.getX());
    }

    //Unimplemented methods
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //Move the ball by resetting the x- and y-position of the ball
        ball.move(xDir, yDir);

        // If ball collides with the paddle, change its vertical direction 
        // Else if it misses the paddle, it will go off of frame
        //blue
        if ((ball.getX() >= paddle1.getX()) &&
                (ball.getX() + ball.getBallWidth() <= paddle1.getX() + paddle1.getWidth())) {
            if (ball.getY() >= (paddle1.getY() - ball.getBallHeight())) {
                xDir = -xDir;
            }
        }
        //red
        else if ((ball.getX() >= paddle3.getX()) &&
                (ball.getX() + ball.getBallWidth() <= paddle3.getX() + paddle3.getWidth())) {
            if (ball.getY() >= (paddle3.getY() - ball.getBallHeight())) {
                xDir = -xDir;
            }
        }
        //yellow
        else if ((ball.getY() >= paddle2.getY()) &&
                (ball.getY() + ball.getBallHeight() <= paddle2.getY() + paddle2.getHeight())) {
            if (ball.getX() >= (paddle2.getX() - ball.getBallWidth())) {
                yDir = -yDir;
            }
        }
        //green
        else if ((ball.getY() >= paddle4.getY()) &&
                (ball.getY() + ball.getBallHeight() <= paddle4.getY() + paddle4.getHeight())) {
            if (ball.getX() >= (paddle4.getX() - ball.getBallWidth())) {
                yDir = -yDir;
            }
        }

        //Check if ball went out on either side and award points accordingly
        else if (ball.getX() + ball.getBallWidth() <= 0) {
            p1Score++;
            ball.setX(getWidth()/2 - ball.getBallWidth()/2);
            ball.setY(getHeight()/2 - ball.getBallHeight()/2);
        }

        else if (ball.getY() + ball.getBallHeight() == 0) {     
            p2Score++;
            ball.setY(getHeight()/2 - ball.getBallHeight()/2);
            ball.setX(getWidth()/2 - ball.getBallWidth()/2);
        }
        else if (ball.getX() + ball.getBallWidth() == 850) {
            p3Score++;
            ball.setX(getWidth()/2 - ball.getBallWidth()/2);
            ball.setY(getHeight()/2 - ball.getBallHeight()/2);
        }
        else if (ball.getX() + ball.getBallHeight() == 850) { 
            p4Score++;
            ball.setY(getHeight()/2 - ball.getBallHeight()/2);
            ball.setX(getWidth()/2 - ball.getBallWidth()/2);
        }
        // Repaint the frame
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        // Draw contents onto the panel
        super.paintComponent (g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Polygon p1 = new Polygon ();
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        p1.addPoint(200, 0);
        p1.addPoint(0, 200);
        p1.addPoint(0, 0);
        g2.fillPolygon(p1);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2.drawLine(200, 0, 0, 200);

        Polygon p2 = new Polygon ();
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        p2.addPoint(625, 0);
        p2.addPoint(850, 225);
        p2.addPoint(850, 0);
        g2.fillPolygon(p2);
        g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2.drawLine(625, 0, 850, 225);

        Polygon p3 = new Polygon ();
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        p3.addPoint(850, 600);
        p3.addPoint(600, 850);
        p3.addPoint(850, 850);
        g2.fillPolygon(p3);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2.drawLine(850, 600, 600, 850);

        Polygon p4 = new Polygon ();
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        p4.addPoint(0, 610);
        p4.addPoint(275, 900);
        p4.addPoint(0, 850);
        g2.fillPolygon(p4);
        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2.drawLine(0, 610, 275, 900);

        ball.draw(g2);
        paddle1.draw(g2);
        paddle2.draw(g2);
        paddle3.draw(g2);
        paddle4.draw(g2);

        // Draw player 1, 2, 3, and 4's scores on panel in the 4 corners
        Font f = new Font( "Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 90);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.setFont(f);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.drawString(""+p1Score, 30, 90);
        g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g2.drawString(""+p2Score, 750, 90);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.drawString(""+p3Score, 750, 775);
        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2.drawString(""+p4Score, 25, 775);

        //Determine winner
        Font f2 = new Font( "Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 75);
        g2.setFont(f2);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if (p1Score == 5) {
            g2.drawString("Player 1 LOSES",150,400);
            t.stop();
        }
        else if (p2Score == 5) {
            g2.drawString("Player 2 LOSES",150,400);
            t.stop();
        }
        else if (p3Score == 5) {
            g2.drawString("Player 3 LOSES",150,400);
            t.stop();
        }
        else if (p4Score == 5) {
            g2.drawString("Player 4 LOSES",150,400);
            t.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ball {
    //Fields
    private int xPos, yPos, ballWidth, ballHeight;
    private ImageIcon imgBall;
    private Color c;
    private boolean useImage;

    //No argument constructor to initialize fields
    public Ball() {
        xPos = 0;
        yPos = 0;
        ballWidth = 50;
        ballHeight = 50;
        imgBall = null;
        c = Color.red;
        useImage = false;
    }

    //Constructor it initialize ball object as an image
    public Ball(int x, int y, ImageIcon img) {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        imgBall = img;
        ballWidth = imgBall.getIconWidth();
        ballHeight = imgBall.getIconHeight();
        c = null;
        useImage = true;
    }

    //Constructor to initialize ball as an oval
    public Ball(int x, int y, int Width, int Height, Color col) {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        ballWidth = Width;
        ballHeight = Height;
        imgBall = null;
        c = col;
        useImage = false;
    }

    //Mutator method to draw the ball as either an image or an oval
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        if(useImage == false) {
            g2.setColor(c);
            g2.fillOval(xPos, yPos, ballWidth, ballHeight);
        }
        else {
            g2.drawImage(getImage(), xPos, yPos, null);
        }
    }

    //Accessor methods to return the values of the fields
    public int getBallHeight() {
        return ballHeight;

    }

    public int getBallWidth() {
        return ballWidth;

    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return imgBall.getImage();

    }

    public int getX() {
        return xPos;

    }

    public int getY() {
        return yPos;

    }

    //Overloaded move() methods
    public void move() {
        xPos += 1;
        yPos += 2;
    }

    public void move(int xDir, int yDir) {
        xPos += xDir;
        yPos += yDir;
    }

    //Mutator methods to set values of the fields
    public void setBallWidth(int width) {
        ballWidth = width;

    }

    public void setBallHeight(int height) {
        ballHeight = height;

    }

    public void setColor (Color col) {
        col = c;

    }

    public void setImageIcon(ImageIcon img) {
        imgBall = img;
    }

    public void setX(int x){
        xPos = x;

    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        yPos = y;

    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Paddle {

    // Fields
    private int xPos, yPos, padWidth, padHeight;
    private Color col;

    // Constructor to initialize paddle fields
    Paddle (int x, int y, int width, int height, Color c) {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        padWidth = width;
        padHeight = height;
        col = c;
    }

    // Mutator method to draw a filled round rectangle
    public void draw (Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.setColor (col);
        g2.fillRoundRect(xPos, yPos, padWidth, padHeight, 30, 30);
    }

    //Accessor methods to return the values of the fields
    public int getHeight() {
        return padHeight;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return padWidth;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return xPos;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return yPos;
    }

    //Mutator methods to change the values of the fields
    public void moveHorizontally (int pixels) {
        xPos += pixels;
    }

    public void moveVertically (int pixels) {
        yPos += pixels;
    }

    public void setHeight (int height) {
        padHeight = height;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        padWidth= width;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        xPos = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        yPos = y;
    }
}
```

I tried to make the paddles have collision and make it so that if the ball scores on one side of the frame, that paddle's side will be given a point. The first to reach 5 points loses.